# Entity Framework: Generated SQL - cannot find data type datetime2

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

So we migrated dev sql server to 2008.

Our UAT sql server is still 2005.

i had to regenerate my entity framework model for some other reasons, and upon deploying my work to UAT i noticed this error:

*cannot find data type datetime2*

I profiled the database, and noticed that Entity Framework generated the input parameter as datetime2!

```
N'@p__linq__0 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0='9999-12-31 00:00:00'
```

this executes fine in dev, because datetime2 is a type there. but fails when deployed to environment with 2005.

Is this some sort of known type? Why is entity framework not using regular datetime, and how can i make it cross environment compatible?

perhaps this is not 2008 upgrade related.. but it wasn't an issue before the upgrade and this code has not changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities produces query containing datetime2 on SQL 2005 Express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350066/linq-to-entities-produces-query-containing-datetime2-on-sql-2005-express)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this 'bug' on MS Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/345018/entity-framework-uses-incompatible-types-e-g-datetime2-when-deployed-to-systems-with-older-sql-server-versions-even-when-source-database-had-compatibility-level-set-correctly) - the workarounds seem to supply a fairly straightforward fix.

Also covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350066/linq-to-entities-produces-query-containing-datetime2-on-sql-2005-express).

Comment: MS Connect has been retired, the stackoverflow link looks fine